# Function to return a data dictionary on a dataframe in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create a function to return a data dictionary for a given data frame. I want a formatted table as the end output (but am unsure if it's best to format the table using kable within the function or on calling it), with column names with spaces in between as defined in the function.

```
data_dict <- function(df, desc = c()){
  data.frame(
    "Variable Name" = names(df),
    "Variable Type" = sapply(df,class),
    "Variable Description" = desc
  )
}
```

I have come across a few problems with my function :

1. sapply() adds another column of data which I do not want.
2. The spaces within the variable names are replaced by periods.

I'm trying to figure out the optimal way to solve these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you are calling your `data_dict` function but this seems to work :

```
data_dict <- function(df, desc = c()){
  data.frame(
    "Variable Name" = names(df),
    "Variable Type" = sapply(df,class),
    "Variable Description" = desc, 
    check.names = FALSE, row.names = NULL
  )
}

data_dict(mtcars[1:2], desc  = c('A', 'B'))
#  Variable Name Variable Type Variable Description
#1           mpg       numeric                    A
#2           cyl       numeric                    B
```

Added `check.names = FALSE` to maintain the spaces in column names and included `row.names = NULL` to remove rownames.